# Converting Multidimensional Array to singe Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Trying to convert this multidimensional array into a single-dimensional one. Hopefully what I said is the best way to describe it. I have a full array which I need to shorten.

```
   $theme = array(
        "1" => array(
            "name" => "one",
            "color" => "red"
        ),
        "2" => array(
            "name" => "two",
            "color" => "green"
        ),
        "3" => array(
            "name" => "three",
            "color" => "pink"
        ),
        "4" => array(
            "name" => "four",
            "color" => "orange"
        ),
        "5" => array(
            "name" => "five",
            "color" => "blue"
        ),
        "6" => array(
            "name" => "six",
            "color" => "black"
        ),

    );
```

I want to reduce it to:

```
 $theme = array("1"=>"red", "2"=>"green", "3"=>"pink", "4"=>"orange", "5"=>"blue", "6"=>"black");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just extract the values from the `color` index:

```
$theme = array_column($theme, 'color');
```

But that will start at `0`.  To start at `1`:

```
$theme = array_combine(range(1, count($theme)), array_column($theme, 'color'));
```

Or if you like, extract `color` and index it by `name`:

```
$theme = array_column($theme, 'color', 'name');
```